# how to convert a list of tuples into a lists of part of tuples in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to convert

```
 l = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
```

to

```
 r = [1, 2]
 p = ['a', 'b']
```

Obviously, looping can be used. is it possible to use lambda? Any other ways

Thanks 
David

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `zip` with `*`:

```
>>> l = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
>>> r, p = zip(*l)
>>> r
(1, 2)
>>> p
('a', 'b')
```

Comment: Zip wins again. Gorgeous function, keep expecting it in every language I use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use list conprehension and create new variable.

```
>>> a = [x[0] for x in l]
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>> p = [x[1] for x in l]
>>> p
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: This is functional but not idiomatic.